# Compilate Kernel on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new working on Ubuntu.

I want re-programe the ethernet module in the kernel space.

After that i need the re-compile all the kernel or just the ethernet module of kernel?

How can i compile the kernel or a module of the kernel?

I already try to build and compile a kernel following this tuturial :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can I ask what it is you want to "reprogram" in your ethernet driver?

My first thought is that if you're in a position where you can modify kernel drivers, compiling a kernel should be well within your abilities -- hence asking what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want to develop above the ethernet device drive somekind of program that will redirect ethernet packets. The finally is to develop an ethernet switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to compile one group of modules, that command is:

```
make M=drivers/net
```

To just make the 'net' group of drivers. The same syntax holds true of any directory under $Linux/drivers. `make install modules` will update the modules on your system. Or, you can just copy the relevant file to the right spot under /lib/modules.

Comment: Useful to know.